# Transferring data from one field to another

Tags: channel-entries, channel, mysql

I have a current checkbox field which contains 8 options.

I want to change this field to a P&T checkbox field, to make use of the `option_name : Option Label` ability.

I've been told I can run an SQL find and replace from within the CP, but I've never done this before.

My field ID for the original field is id=6, and the new one is id=38

Can anyone help me with how I can transfer (or copy) the channel entires data from one field to another? Thanks!

**Update**

Thanks for the suggestions, will take a look at the fields now, and try it out.

Just so I'm sure i'm not doing anything unnecessarily, I am moving the data to a P&T field, as I need the ability to put the label and value. In order for the following code to work...

```
{walk_features_new}

    <li class="{option_name}"><strong>{option}</strong>
     <p>
      {if "{option_name}" == "option1"}Description for option 1{/if}
      {if "{option_name}" == "option2"}Description for option 2{/if}
      {if "{option_name}" == "option3"}Description for option 3{/if}
      {if "{option_name}" == "option4"}Description for option 4{/if}
      {if "{option_name}" == "option5"}Description for option 5{/if}
      {if "{option_name}" == "option6"}Description for option 6{/if}
      {if "{option_name}" == "option7"}Description for option 7{/if}
      {if "{option_name}" == "option8"}Description for option 8{/if}
    </p>
    </li>                               {/walk_features_new}
```

I am right in think that this would not be do-able with the standard checkbox field, as I could only output the `{option}` right?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can run this SQL:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET field_id_38=REPLACE(field_id_6, "|", "\n")
```

Where field with id 38 would be P&T checkboxes and field with id 6 would be checkboxes.

This SQL would work fine although it would be better if you can take a backup of database table exp_channel_data.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just tried it, but nothing has changed?

Comment: I am not sure if this sql didn't work. did you get any error message?

Comment: No error message, no. It actually says "Your query was successful" but non of the P&T checkboxes are now filled?

Comment: well, if you know the checkbox field type store the values separated with pipe ("|") while P&T checkbox stores the values separated with new line so in the query you can see first I am replacing "|" with "\n" of old checkbox field (id 6) and then that is being copied into into new P&T checkbox field (id 38).